# SQL or PL/SQL to return the value of nodes with same name to one row

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

From the below XML I would like to return the following.

```
ID            Departments
-----------   ------------------------------   
EMP10Level1   98,850,876,896,901,908,936,987
```

I have tried a few things, such as parsing the XML and using Listagg, but am getting the same values for every ID.

Hopefully a more enlightenment mind can solve this problem for me.

Is also a column called ID that contains EMP10Level1 which is the value from the PromotionID tag below.

```
 <Promotion>
    <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion>7</MinorVersion>
    <PromotionID>EMP10Level1</PromotionID>
    <MultibuyGroup>
        <UseLowestNetValue>0</UseLowestNetValue>
        <MMGroupID>850</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>901</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>908</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>936</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>896</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>987</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>876</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>98</MMGroupID>
        <TriggerOnLostSales>0</TriggerOnLostSales>
    </MultibuyGroup>
</Promotion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using sort-of-nested XMLTABLEs:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT XMLTYPE('<Promotion>
    <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
    <MinorVersion>7</MinorVersion>
    <PromotionID>EMP10Level1</PromotionID>
    <MultibuyGroup>
        <UseLowestNetValue>0</UseLowestNetValue>
        <MMGroupID>850</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>901</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>908</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>936</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>896</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>987</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>876</MMGroupID>
        <MMGroupID>98</MMGroupID>
        <TriggerOnLostSales>0</TriggerOnLostSales>
    </MultibuyGroup>
</Promotion>') xmldata FROM dual)
SELECT ids.id,
       listagg(depts.department, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depts.department) departments
FROM   sample_data sd
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/Promotion' PASSING sd.xmldata
                           COLUMNS ID VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'PromotionID',
                                   dept_xml XMLTYPE PATH 'MultibuyGroup') ids
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('//MMGroupID' PASSING ids.dept_xml
                           COLUMNS department INTEGER PATH '.') depts
GROUP BY ids.id;

ID                   DEPARTMENTS
-------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMP10Level1          98,850,876,896,901,908,936,987
```

Comment: Excellent solution, amended it to refererence my actual DB columns and it is pulling out the data as required. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but here is another which works:

```
WITH TBL
     AS (SELECT xmltype (
                   '<Promotion>
                    <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
                    <MinorVersion>7</MinorVersion>
                    <PromotionID>EMP10Level1</PromotionID>
                    <MultibuyGroup>
                        <UseLowestNetValue>0</UseLowestNetValue>
                        <MMGroupID>850</MMGroupID>
                        <MMGroupID>901</MMGroupID>
                        <MMGroupID>908</MMGroupID>
                        <MMGroupID>936</MMGroupID>
                        <MMGroupID>896</MMGroupID>
                        <MMGroupID>987</MMGroupID>
                        <MMGroupID>876</MMGroupID>
                        <MMGroupID>98</MMGroupID>
                        <TriggerOnLostSales>0</TriggerOnLostSales>
                    </MultibuyGroup>
                </Promotion>')
                   Col1
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (col1, 'Promotion/PromotionID') AS ID,
       LTRIM (
          REPLACE (
             REPLACE (EXTRACT (col1, 'Promotion/MultibuyGroup/MMGroupID'),
                      '<MMGroupID>',
                      ','),
             '</MMGroupID>'),
          ',')
          AS DEPT
  FROM tbl
```

Comment: I would highly recommend the OP tests both mine and this answer to see which one is more performant for their case. I have found XMLTABLE to be faster than EXTRACT/EXTRACTVALUE, but that may just have been in that particular scenario (which is not this one). I'd be interested to see the results, particularly if this answer is more performant *{:-)